# How can I copy & paste the text in Electron with single keyboard shortcut?

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, electron

I'm working on Electron project in which I want to combine 3 features with single command strokes. Copy the selected text, open the file and paste in the textbox. But currently, I'm only able to do it with 2 key presses, Ctrl+C for copy and custom shortcut for opening the file and paste it. I searched online and found some tools like browserify but they are not useful because I want this to work in PDFs, text file or web browser. Any help from you guys would be of huge help

Comment: sounds like AutoHotkey macro would help you

Comment: @fard as far as I know I can't use AutoHotkey in Electron. What do you suggest?

Comment: Is this related to Atom at all? If it's just the editor you use, please remove the tag – it's unrelated to the question.